# i have confusion in getting subcategories i want to echo each subcatagory only one time..

Tags: php

Please help me i have confusion in getting categories i want to echo each subcatagory only one time..

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die(mysql_error())//connect to mysql;
mysql_select_db("ubcommerce")//select database;
$catagories = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY subcatagory DESC")//select data from table;
$found = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($found > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        // Gather all $row values into local variables for easier usage in output 
        $subcatagory = $row['subcatagory'];
        $link = $row['catagory'];
        $link = lcfirst($link);
        $catagories .= "<li>$subcatagory</li>";
    }
} else {
    $catagories = "you have no product in your list yet";
}
?>

<html>
    <body>

    <div class="col-content">
        <ul>
<?php echo $catagories; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no semicolon at the end of the first two lines (putting it at the end of the comment doesn't work, you have to put it after the closing parenthesis).

Comment: The same problem exists on line 4

Comment: Do you get any output or error message? Can you post it here?

Comment: i m getting this output cameras,cameras,cameras,TV,TV,TV,TV, because there are more than 1 items with same subcatagory how can i get each subcatagory name only 1 time?

Comment: The easiest solution is to write the query like: `SELECT DISTINCT subcatagory FROM inventory ORDER BY subcatagory DESC`.

Comment: OK thanks dude you solved my problem, well i m new in php

Comment: No problem. If you think this really solved the problem you can accept the answer I just posted (by clicking the check mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to the problem detailed in the comments is to write the query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subcatagory FROM inventory ORDER BY subcatagory DESC
```

(though it may not scale well)

Answer (score 0):

use pdo ;)

```
<?php
//connect to your db
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'ubcommerce');
//prepare your request
$bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY subcatagory DESC');
//exec your request
$bdd->execute();
//put your reponse into an array
$rep = $bdd->fetchAll();
//run your array
foreach($rep as $subCategory){
    echo $subCategory['catagory'];
}
```

Comment: i m getting this error now  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp\www\ubcommerce\test.php on line 35

Comment: Though using PDO is good practice, this doesn't have to do anything with the actual question being asked. Also, there are errors in it: you should've written `$statement = $bdd->prepare(whatever); $statement->execute();`